# In Android SQLite db how to match particular columns values which have same id's in multiple tables of a database?

Tags: android, sqlite

I had dumped data into SQLite from Json data that I am getting. Now my question is I have a single database with multiple tables I want to relate multiple tables using there id's.These are the 3 tables I had created.

This is first table where we have product list,

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_PRODUCT =
            "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + "product_template" + " (" +
                    "_id" + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
                    "name" + "," +
                    "list_price" + "," +
                    "create_date" + "," +
                    "default_code" + "," +
                    "ean13" + "," +
                    "image_new" + "," +
                    "image_variant" +
                    ");";
```

This is second table where we have partner list,

```
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_PARTNER =
            "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + "res_partner" + " (" +
                    "_id" + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
                    "phone" + "," +
                    "mobile" + "," +
                    "name" +
                    ");";
```

This is third table where we have account line,

```
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_LINE =
            "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + "account_invoice_line" + " (" +
                    "product_id" + "," +
                    "partner_id" +
                    ");";
```

In third table I have two columns product_id and partner_id, I should match values of partner_id with **second table** column _id and I should get values of name column in it and through values in column partner_id I should match with **first table** _id and I should get values in name column.

Can any one help in creating relation between this tables?

Comment: err i am not so hot in the areas of SQL, but I do believe I am accurate to say that you are signing up to maintain an additional table. An alternative to maintaining a third table would be a SQL join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT t1.name prod_name, t2.name part_name from product_template t1, res_partner t2, account_invoice_line t3 where t3.product_id = t1.id and t3.partner_id = t2.id
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to use your query as raw query in my android app?

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to get the data, you are probably looking for SQL JOINS.

[image]